# How can I display a repeating date field in Drupal?

Tags: datetime, drupal

I have a custom content type called `events` in which uses a field called `event_date`. When I set the date and look at the node, it correctly shows the date I entered: 
[image]

However, when I do a `dpm` on `node_insert` to see the values getting saved, here is what's being reported to me:

[image]

As you can see, this is not what I entered in and these are the exact values that gets stored in the database as well.

My questions:

1) How can I get the correct values? (I'd like to get 03/30/2016 and 7:00pm)

2) Why are these values different but the node still shows them correctly? where the time being saved?

Thanks

Comment: What does the offset value mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answer for second question and then you will easier find answer to first one also.

You see offset of -18000. 
That is 300 minutes.
Which equals to 5 hours.

2016-03-31 00:00 -(minus) 5 hours is 2016-03-30 07:00pm

So you need to use function to format date that will include that offset also. Check comments and links from: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/33686/32059

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing this and I was able to get the right date: `GmtTimeToLocalTime($event_date['value'],$event_date['timezone']);`